# How to append current date and time to log file name usng audit trail plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to generate a log file using Jenkins Audit trial. I am able to generate a log file but I want thr log files name to be appended with the current date and time.

Currently I get the output as Audit-0.0.log

I expect the output as Audit-0.0_dd-mm-yyyy.log

Below image shows the configuraton.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that currently there is no such option for [Audit Trail Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Audit+Trail+Plugin). From the documentation:

> The file logger relies on java.util.logging.FileHandler and can use patterns to describe the log file location as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) (%h, %g...).

As you can see from [FileHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) page, there are no pattern for specifying a date:

> A pattern consists of a string that includes the following special components that will be replaced at runtime:
>
> - "/" the local pathname separator
> - "%t" the system temporary directory
> - "%h" the value of the "user.home" system property
> - "%g" the generation number to distinguish rotated logs
> - "%u" a unique number to resolve conflicts
> - "%%" translates to a single percent sign "%"
>
> If no "%g" field has been specified and the file count is greater than one, then the generation number will be added to the end of the generated filename, after a dot.